# Local limit theorem for an infinite dimensional integer lattice

Tags: pr.probability, hilbert-spaces, limit-theorems

Can someone refer me to a local limit theorem for the sum ${\bf S} = \sum_{i=1}^n{\bf X}_i$ of a sequence of independent and identically distributed $d$-dimensional random variables $\{{\bf X}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ as $n \to \infty$, such that ${\bf X}_i \in \mathbb{Z}^{d}$ ($d$-dimensional integer lattice)? In particular, I am looking for such a theorem for $d = \infty$.

I do not have a strong background in mathematics but I am fairly certain that this must be a well-studied problem (perhaps expressed in some other manner); the case of $d < \infty$ certainly is.

Thanks in advance!